# Get value from xml tags which are of same name using xpaths

Tags: java, xpath, xml-parsing

I publish some csv input file on a server and it gives me a xml file that looks like this:

```
<ns0:TransportationEvent xmlns:ns0="http://www.server.com/schemas/TransportationEvent.xsd">
<ns0:creationDateTime>2017-04-06</ns0:creationDateTime>
.....
.....
</ns0:TransportationEvent>

<ns0:TransportationEvent xmlns:ns0="http://www.fedex.com/schemas/TransportationEvent.xsd">
<ns0:creationDateTime>2017-04-25</ns0:creationDateTime>
.....
.....
</ns0:TransportationEvent>
```

The **TransportationEvent** tag would be added again and again with the updated date in it.

I am retrieving data from this xml using XpathFactory class and NamespaceContext class which is shown as below:

```
NamespaceContext ctx = new NamespaceContext() { 
        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) { 
            String uri; 
            if (prefix.equals("ns0")) 
                uri = "http://www.server.com/schemas/TransportationEvent.xsd"; 
            else 
                uri = null; 
            return uri; 
        } 
        public Iterator getPrefixes(String val) { 
            return null; 
        } 
        // Dummy implementation - not used! 
        public String getPrefix(String uri) { 
            return null; 
        } 
    };

XPathFactory xpathFact = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpathFact.newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(ctx);

String strXpath = "//ns0:TransportationEvent/ns0:creationDateTime/text()";       
String creationDateTime = xpath.evaluate(strXpath, doc);
```

The above code gives the value of **creationDateTime** as *2017-04-06*. Basically it always take values from the first **TransportationEvent** tag.

I need to pick data from that "**TransportationEvent**" tag where the "**creationDateTime**" is equal to today's date.

I can perform this by using NodeList class and can iterate through all the "**TransportationEvent**" tags but then I would not be able to use the Xpath or NamespaceContext implementation. I am finding no connection between the NodeList class and the NamespaceContext class or the Xpath class.

I want to get the value of ***ctx*** which has the context of the latest **TransportationEvent** tag.

I know I am missing something. Could somebody help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `last()` function in a predicate to select only the last `TransportationEvent`:

```
String strXpath = "//ns0:TransportationEvent[last()]/ns0:creationDateTime/text()";
```

Comment: This works just like I wanted. Thanks.

Is this a good way to parse xml using Namespacecontext and xpathFactory classes?

I have xml files which have huge content in them. Using nodeList and nodes will make the code difficult to manage. Am i right here?

Comment: You are right on track. Navigating through a DOM using node methods is totally unreadable, whereas XPath is very short and concise.